# Reading a ngx-datatable table with vba

Tags: vba, html-table, ngx-datatable

I'm connecting to a webpage with VBA & the data i need to iterate thru is in a ngx-datatable table. But when i connect to the table it doesn't recognize it as an IHTMLtable. If i set the element as a generic IHTMLEelement type it won't error out but it identifies itself as "objHTMLunknownelement", then when I try to loop the rows it throws an error. I was hoping to do this one like I do others, start at row 0, go thru the cells, capture what I need and make sure its in the date range I want & then stop once i pass out of the date range. Can I connect to this & treat it like a regular table & if so how do I declare the element type.  Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code. Is the url public? You will need to reconstruct the "table" from the angular elements.

Comment: It's not a table at all except in the sense it *appears* like one in the browser - just a set of divs.  And since the top-level tag `<ngx-datatable>` is not a "standard" HTML element it's not too surprising that it comes over as "unknownelement"

Comment: QHarr, I'll post on Monday when I'm back at the office. The website is not public. If it wont work as a table I can probably build something logically on the Div's. I've never tried referencing an element with a variable in the name but i'm sure that should be ok. I can just start at zero & add 1 when i want to move rows. The cells are fixed so i can just jump to the few columns that are relevant. I was just hoping to use the structure I'm familar with. I'll post back Monday. Thank you guys.

Comment: If the variable is part of an attribute value that is easy to handle with css attribute selectors via querySelector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. Can you include the relevant html/angular if not in breach of any conditions? The approach by Tim Williams in answer is also an effective method but if variable(s) for attributes are involved you can gain better efficiencies with querySelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (using the example URL in the code)

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim Explorer As Object, doc, tbls, tr, tds, td, tbl, rws, rw
    Dim r As Long
    Set Explorer = GetIEByUrl("https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/*")
    
    Set doc = Explorer.document
    
    Set tbls = doc.getElementsByTagName("ngx-datatable")
    Debug.Print tbls.Length '>> 1
    Set rws = tbls(0).getElementsByTagName("datatable-body-row")
    Debug.Print rws.Length  '>> 100
    
    r = 0
    For Each rw In rws
        r = r + 1
        Debug.Print "**** Row " & r & " ****"
        Set tds = rw.getElementsByTagName("datatable-body-cell")
        For Each td In tds
            Debug.Print td.innerText
        Next td
    Next rw
  
End Sub
```

GetIEByURL:

```vb
'return an open IE tab given a [partial] URL
Function GetIEByUrl(URL As String) As Object
    Dim o As Object, rv As Object
    For Each o In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If TypeName(o) = "IWebBrowser2" And o.Name <> "File Explorer" Then
            If o.document.Location Like "*" & URL & "*" Then
                Set rv = o
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetIEByUrl = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Tim, thank you for the suggestion, I was able to move forward with minimal changes to my code. Mainly the way we can assign the rows & cells "manually" and the rest just works.Thank you